# DuplicateHandle 32/64 bit processes

Tags: 64-bit

I have two processes, one 32-bits, another 64-bits and I need to duplicate some handles that are used by the other process.

In x64, HANDLE size is enough to hold the 32-bit handle but when I call DuplicateHandle in the x86 process targetting the x64 one, does the o.s. ensures that the resulting handle will fit in 32-bit HANDLE type?

Regards,
Mauro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows will manage it, its stated in the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724251%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the call;

> DuplicateHandle can be used to duplicate a handle between a 32-bit
>   process and a 64-bit process. The resulting handle is appropriately
>   sized to work in the target process

Comment: Yes but doubt is the following: I have a 32-bit handle and the target process is 64-bit. I want to believe that the duplicated handle I obtain in the x86 DuplicateHandle call (targetting 64-bit process) fits the 32-bit HANDLE type.

Comment: It works either way http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2005/01/31/363881.aspx